# How can I drop/sell Black Books without breaking anything?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-dragonborn

According to the wiki, and multiple discussions, Dragonborn Black Books (of Hermaneous-Mora) remain as quest items and cannot be dropped or sold even after the relevant quests are complete.

These discussions may be outdated. Are Black Books still not droppable even in the special edition?

To try to solve this I've looked at the mod [Black Books Begone](http://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/31807/?) and [Droppable Dragonborn Black Books](http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=186893874), but they each have drawbacks: the first lets you drop them only in a specific house, the second appears to have a lot of bugs.

I also imagine there are ways using the console, but I haven't been able to figure out how to accomplish that safely.

How can I drop Black Books, **without** causing their quests to break, introducing bugs, or interfering with any mods?

Solutions that work for either the Special Edition, or the Non Special Edition, would both help.

Comment: What is up with the downvotes?

Comment: The reason you're getting downvotes is that this boils down to asking for recommendations of mods that meet the criteria you've mentioned, which is considered off-topic here.

Comment: Only the last point is about a mod, I think this could be covered by console commands.

Comment: You're asking for very specific criteria, leading me to believe you still want a mod that handles all of this.  Rather than get this specific, just tell us your problem.  Leave it to the answers to solve it.

Comment: According to the meta and precedence, this is a perfectly valid question, especially after I've edited it. 

http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/5547/closed-mod-recommendation-skyrim-question-can-this-question-be-improved-and

Also:

http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/8147/the-community-is-closing-mod-rec-questions?noredirect=1&lq=1

Accordingly, my problem is that I want Black Books to not be quest items after the completion of the relevant quests. Without breaking the game. The parameters gives a definition of what breaking the game is.

Comment: Your second link has the most voted answer as, yes, we are closing mod-rec questions.  Look, we get it.  You want a mod that does all these things.  Great.  Unfortunately, that's not useful to anyone but you.  What would be, however, is anyone else who wants a solution, any solution, to the same problem.  Focus on the specific problem.  Not how you want it solved.

Comment: How do you propose I state the question better then? As most of the answers in the meta questions have agreed upon, the question of "How do I do X" is acceptable. 

My question is exactly that I want to have the black books be non quest items after the relevant quests, with some caveats. I highly doubt that the answer is useless to everyone else.

Comment: You're focusing on exactly what you want the solution to do.  That's less a problem, and more a, "Find me something that does all this" solution request.  Your main problem is you want to be able to drop black books.  All the rest beyond that is superflous.  Answers can recommend a mod that does it, but might have some caveats.  Regardless, the best solution will bubble to the top with votes, while allowing you to choose which one helped you the most by accepting it.

Comment: Please do not assume what my problem is and what is superfluous. If I just wanted to drop black books, some basic console commands will get the job done. The question does not suffer from the XY problem. The 5 main criteria are not proposed solutions to an overarching problem, but rather 5 parameters that the solution should meet. Any solution which does not somewhat meet these 5 parameters is not a solution.

I specifically want black books to become non quest items upon the completion of the relevant quests.

Comment: And hence why it's a recommendation request; you're looking for a very specific solution to this problem.  No, this isn't an X/Y problem, but it is very much outside our purview.  We've had other questions like this, and the only way we can keep them is by bringing the problem to the fore, and removing the cruft.  If you want this question to be reopened, I'd recommend following my advice.

Comment: At best, I can add a succinct summary:

How do I have the black books become non quest items after the relevant quest has been completed without affecting anything else, and still maintain all compatibility with mods?

If you wish me to add this summary, please tell me so.

Comment: It is not a recommendation request. This question does not request for a mod. As the 2 meta links I've shown have indicated, the question, after I have reworded it, is a valid question. 

I am not looking for a specific solution. I have a specific question; a specific question that is not even that specific, honestly. If you believe that this question should be closed, please link the relevant meta discussion, and give the relevant information.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52900/discussion-between-frank-and-fluidized-pigeon-reactor).

Comment: Ignoring the conversation that happened here, the mod you hope for probably won't exist for Special Edition until SKSESE  exists, as there are scripts tied to the behavior of Black Books when they are selected or picked up. If they are put down without a special "holder" they would fire events that would get very glitchy, especially if you already completed the Dragonborn expansion.

Comment: I've edited the question to demonstrate what we're expecting questions to look like. Instead of requesting a bespoke solution be crafted to-spec, it simply presents the problem: wanting to drop Black Books without it causing any problems. That leaves it wide open to let the answer-writers do their job properly: solve the problem in the best possible way (perhaps a way the asker wouldn't even predict), instead of merely the requested way.

Comment: I honestly did not realize the same mod I linked was mentioned in the original question, so I feel a bit dumb, but I added the (only) non-mod option to remove these items from your inventory to my answer.

Comment: Yeah, the question seems a lot better. Thanks, sevensideddie.

Comment: Why do you want to get rid of these books so badly? They are Weightless quest items, after all. They have no bearing on how much your character can haul around. Should you decide you want to change powers available in the books, you'll be glad you have them on you and don't have to try and find them. Sure they clutter up the books category of your inventory a bit, but that is a small price to pay for the ability to swap powers. Personally, I swap between the various powers in Sallow Regent frequently. It would be an annoying extra few steps to have to grab the book each time, then put it back.

Comment: @Jtenorj3 Because I want to.

Answer (score 3):

There's a mod specifically designed to remove the Black Books from your inventory, which you can find [here](http://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/31807/?), though I do not know whether you can use this mod on the special edition or not. (As an aside, according to the page for the mod, this mod has caused 0 computers to blow up, so that's a good sign it won't break your game.)

If you don't want to use a mod, it looks like you could also use console commands to remove them from your inventory (as well as add them to a container). The relevant console commands would be:

```
player.drop [item ID]
```

and

```
additem [item ID] [quantity]
```

The item IDs for the black books are `XX016E2C`, `XX01E99E`, `XX01E99F`, `XX01E99D`, `XX01E99C`, `XX016E2D`, and `XX016E22`.

It's worth mentioning that according to a user [here](https://forums.nexusmods.com/index.php?/topic/1074546-are-the-black-books-quest-items-forever/), picking up one of the books again will cause you to be teleported back to Apocrypha, so be wary of that if you choose to put the Black Books somewhere other than your inventory.

> Now that I've messed with it, I realize there is a very good reason why the Black Books remain quest items forever.  If you were to drop one, you wouldn't be able to pick it up without getting sent to Apocrypha.

Also, this sort of goes without saying based on the nature of the books, but you most likely want to be completely done with the Dragonborn questline before removing these books from your inventory, or else you might break something.